# NSNotification observer not being removed unless it has been triggered once

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nsnotifications

**In summary**

If a user takes a photo with an overlay on VC1 it triggers a notification. The corresponding observer gets removed by my method as a I present VC2.

If the user doesn't take a photo on VC1, the notification observer isn't trigger. The same removal method is called as VC2 is presented but the observer stays active and causes unwanted behaviours with VC2 photo capture.

**Full explanation**

I have a registration form where a user can take an optional photo of their face. I'm using a simple `UIImagePickerController` and presenting a 'passport' style overlay.

```
if sourceType == .camera {
    imagePickerController.cameraDevice = .front
    let overlay = PassportOverlayView(frame: imagePickerController.view.frame)
    imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlay
}
```

The overlay covers the 'retake' and 'choose' buttons of the `UIImagePickerController` so I observe the following `NSNotifications` to remove the overlay when a photo taken, and re-add it if required should the user wish to retake their photo.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"), object:nil, queue:nil, using: { note in
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = nil
})
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"), object:nil, queue:nil, using: { note in
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = PassportOverlayView(frame: self.imagePickerController.view.frame)
})
```

Everything works as intended. I remove the notifications before the next `UIViewController` is pushed onto the stack.

```
func removeObservers(){
    print("remove Observers")
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"), object: nil)
}
```

If the user has taken a photo and therefore called the observer adding a photo on the next `UIViewController`, which doesn't require an overlay, works fine.

If however, the user doesn't take a photo on the first `UIViewController` [which is perfectly fine for the purposes of my app] they run into an issue on the second `UIViewController`.

In both scenerios the `removeObservers()` function is called. "remove Observers" is printed to the console on both occasions. Yet when the users tries to take a photo from within the second `UIViewController` the app crashes as it `Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` and points me to the `self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = nil` line of the `_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem` notification.

I understand the error, it's trying to remove a `cameraOverlayView` that isn't there. What I can't understand is why the observer is still there when I believe it's already been removed. If the user takes the first photo with the `cameraOverlayView` and triggers the `_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem` notification there isn't an issue. The observer is removed and subsequent `UIImagePickerControllers` don't have the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about removing observers anymore (since iOS9). So you try running your code without the removeObservers function and see if that works.

Comment: If that doesn't work, assign your observer to a variable and use that variable to call removeObserver: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver

Comment: Thanks @rs7, I'd previously tried without to see if iOS did it for me but no joy. Using variables didn't change anything either. I'm still left with the odd scenario of the observer being removed only once it's been used on ViewController 1

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what your problem is. A retain cycle is causing the observer to not be removed successfully. The reason why you have a retain cycle is because you are using a strong reference to self in the closure where you set your notifications. Here is how you fix it:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"), object:nil, queue:nil, using: { [unowned self] note in
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = nil
})
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"), object:nil, queue:nil, using: { [unowned self] note in
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = PassportOverlayView(frame: self.imagePickerController.view.frame)
})
```

Again, you shouldn't have to worry about removing the observers, so try to run your code without removeObserver and it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try adding ```[unowned self]``` as you suggest. Still can't understand why it removes if used but remove if it isn't within my original code.

Comment: Did using [unowned self] solved your problem? Your remove observer function is called from deinit?

Comment: I’m yet to try it. I will try first thing tomorrow morning. I don’t call the remove observer from deinit, it’s simply called within the action of a button tap which pushes the next VC onto the stack. I don’t see how using the image picker controller would mean there isn’t a retain cycle though??

Comment: Well, I'm a bit confused myself. I don't know if it's a retain cycle or a memory leak. Using self inside your closure means there is a strong reference pointing to UIImagePickerController. When you are moving away from UIImagePickerController by clicking the button, because of that strong reference, UIImagePickerController is not being deallocated. Now the confusing part is why removeObserver doesn't work. I'm really curious to see if [unowned self] will solve your problem. Meanwhile, I'll keep on digging.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. ```[unowned self] hasn't made a difference. The memory graph isn't showing any kind of leak or retain cycle either.

Comment: I posted the query to a Reddit group also and received feedback that has solved my issue. I'll answer the question with the details.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your issue. Looking forward to finding out what the fix was.

Comment: He should removeObservers, only add observer with selector way and after iOS 9, no need to worry about unregister observers.